# Responsive graphs: Get width and height of axis, so graph can take up remaining size of a container

Tags: javascript, d3.js

tl;dr, solve for the x-axis and y-axis dimensions.

Container dimensions:
Height: 500px
Width: 500px

X Axis dimensions:
**Height: ?
Width: ?**

Y Axis dimensions:
**Height: ?**
**Width: ?**

Graph dimensions:
Height: container.height - xAxis.height;
Width:  container.width - yAxis.width;

**Details:**

A user uploads data, and my application creates a graph. The graph and axis should render nicely in a 500px square container. This is easy, until we add axises. The axis vary in width (y-axis text) or height (x-axis text if it's rotated vertical).

I haven't seen any examples yet that start with a container size, subtract the axis sizes, and then render the graph in the remainder. (container - axis = graph dimensions). How can this be accomplished?

The problem is d3.svg.axis() needs a scale. This scale uses a d3.scale.range(), which uses your graph height. The problem is the graph height is (container height - x axis height).  And we can't calculate the x-axis since it depends on the y-axis width!

I've considered one solution, which is take the maximum bounding box for all the text that *could* make up the ticks, then add in the height or width of the axis line. Obviously this can be a huge calculation in a large dataset. I can do some smart things like find the maximum and hope it's the longest in pixels. However, this all seems messy, and I'm sure it's a problem anyone creating dynamic graphs would have run into.

Comment: when you are binding the `svg` to the `div` in `d3`, it already means you are putting it in a container. You can adjust the margin via  `attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + margin.top + ")")`

Comment: By translating the SVG, you are causing the container to be 500px + the margin. The question requires you to keep the 500px by 500px dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

Fit d3 graph into specific pixel: 500 x 500

**HTML**

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Give no room for margin to get full pixels

**JS**

```
var  width = 500,
     height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/QBDGB/175/)

Picture to prove svg is giving a full 500 x 500 resolution

[image: 500x500]

Comment: Your graph does not fit into a 500px by 500px space.

Comment: In new JSfiddle, i set the margin to 0 to give the full pixel graph, check is it what you want?

Comment: Your graph still does not fit into a 500px by 500px space. I appreciate your effort, but the purpose of this question is to figure out how to get graphs to scale responsively to fit within a contained space. The graph in your jsfiddle is much larger than 500px.

Comment: I refine my answer, in my previous answer, I forgot there is an internal declaration for the `svg` size. Apologize for that.

Comment: That's HTML, not a picture of your graph. Measure your picture.